# ApiController is not showing actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have an API controller where I'll code some POST and GET actions, but I don't know why they're not appearing on Swagger/Help.. I can't use them.

```
public class ApoliceController : ApiController
{
    private GV db = new GV();

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult ListStatus()
    {
        Ok(db.EthereumStatus.ToList());
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult ListApolices()
    {
        Ok(db.ApoliceEthereum.ToList());
    }
}
```

And my route wasn't customized:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Can  someone help with that?

Regards,

Comment: I would recommend you to use attribute routing, improves readability and its easier to configure IMO

Comment: Convention-based routing uses the method name to determine the HTTP method to support.  Rename your methods so they start with `Get`.

Answer (score 0):

These methods routes to the same endpoint url api/apolice which makes no sense

Instead use different routes

```
[RoutePrefix("api/apolice")]
public class ApoliceController : ApiController
{
    private GV db = new GV();

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("statuses")] //route will be api/apolice/status
    public void ListStatus()
    {
        Ok(db.EthereumStatus.ToList());
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")] //route will be api/apolice
    public void ListApolices()
    {
        Ok(db.ApoliceEthereum.ToList());
    }
}
```

Comment: That works! Work with ApiController is a little bit different from a normal Controller...

Comment: Resource paths representing collections should be named with plurals, so it should be `/statuses`.

Comment: @Mauricionik great that it helped. please accept answer/upvote

Comment: @MarcusHöglund As soonest I've 15 reputation I'll.. Thanks (: